# Right floatting precedence in CSS

Tags: css

Having

```css
.right { float: right }
.suffix { background:pink }
.container { background:lightblue }
.container::after {content:'>>'; background: lightblue; float: right; }
.container::before {content:'<<'; background: lightblue; float: left; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Offer Title
    <div class="right suffix">ID
```

How should I do to make `ID` appear **before** the `>>`

http://codepen.io/serhio/pen/EyZyZa?editors=1100

Answer (score 2):

Flexbox can do that:

```css
.right {
  margin-left: auto;
}
.suffix {
  background: pink
}
.container {
  background: lightblue;
  display: flex;
}
.container::after {
  content: '>>';
  background: lightblue;
}
.container::before {
  content: '<<';
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Offer Title
  <div class="right suffix">ID</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need a IE compatible solution... (

Comment: Flexbox is IE compatible.

Comment: is it a way just by playing with `suffix`? Is a new element, so too much modifications with the ancient ones will broke the site...

Comment: There are no new elements. I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: I mean, initially there where no suffix on the page... everything worked well, now I have to add the suffix, but do not broken the ancient design

Comment: Afraid that IE does not really like "flex": http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: If you have a specific IE in mind you should add that to the question. Flexbox is supported by IE10/11 and Edge.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `:after` for container use it for .suffix

```css
.right {float: right}
.suffix {background:pink;}
.container{background:lightblue}
.suffix::after {content:'>>'; background: lightblue; float: right; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Offer Title
    <div class="right suffix">ID
```

Comment: This is the most logical option.

Comment: not bad solution, but is it possible do not modify the suffix father's style? just playing with "suffix"... Cause if the ID is hidden, I will loose the >>, not good...

Comment: use position then. see new answer i have posted

Answer (score 0):

Use :before instead of :after

https://jsfiddle.net/ex3ntia/4pn4jwn8/

```
.container::before {content:'>>'; background: lightblue; float: right; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is updating this with `position`

```css
.right {position: absolute; right: 33px; top:0;}
.suffix {background:pink;}
.container{background:lightblue;  position: relative;}
.container::after {content:'>>'; background: lightblue; position: absolute;right: 0; width: 30px; text-align:center;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Offer Title
    <div class="right suffix">ID New
```